# Best practices to deal with web application sessions from a Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, session, cookies, cors

I've read nearly all posts on Stack Overflow regarding the topic session handling within Cordova apps, but none of them seems to touch the whole process from a best practices view.

To sum up what I've learned so far:

1.) Cordova apps usually deliver their web content from the mobile devices filesystem (which means the local /www directory of the Cordova project), not the hosted instance of a web application.

2.) If the application needs to deal with session cookie(s) set by the server backend, an (additional) preceding AJAX request is required to get that session cookie information transfered to the Cordova app implicitely and without having to deal with document.cookie and/or localStorage peristency on client side.

3.) In order to get this AJAX request working AND transmit the session data successfully, CORS neeeds to be enabled on server side and the transmission of session data enabled:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // possible security issue
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // even more evil possible security issue
```

4.) If the application targets Lollipop (= API level 21) or above for the Android platform, it must be secured that the following has been included in YourApplication.java (= file containing the MainActivity class) in the Function "onCreate":

```
CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
```

If I'm getting things right, this seems to open a lot of (hopefully) unnecessary security holes to the backend. So I am asking myself: is this really a common used pattern, or are there any better best practices around to cover the described scenario?

Perhaps I should add, that in my case a normal web client gets a session cookie back by already doing the initial page load of the application. This is required, as the application assigns an auto-incrementing (e.g.) guest_72385 nickname to the user on his first connect, as he must be able to join parts of the application without having to login but nonetheless needs to use a unique username.